# Posted data won't INSERT into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, mariadb

I had this similar issue before where HTML form data would get passed to a PHP script but then not get inserted into the database. So I ended up redoing the form entirely and it just worked. So onto another form with different (less) data -- I only changed form names. So again, I can see the form data in the header, I have all the spelling, capitalization, and field order the same. I can echo the variables, but cannot get the information to insert into the database table (a different table) for the life of me, nor do I get any warnings from MariaDB.

What is going wrong?

var_dump($query);

string(231) "INSERT INTO datavalidator (lotnum, description, serial, sanitationmethod, validationmethod, passfail, failcomment, validationemployee) VALUES ('12','device','serial','HD Shredder 4','xxd','1','Passed','employee');"

DB
(mysql-mariadb 10)

```
MariaDB [r2inventory]> show columns from datavalidator;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| date               | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| lotnum             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| description        | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| serial             | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| sanitizationmethod | varchar(140) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| validationmethod   | varchar(140) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| passfail           | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| validationemployee | varchar(48)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| failcomment        | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

config.inc.php

```php
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "r2inventory";
$db_table = "datavalidator";

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
if(!$link) die ('Could not connect to database: '.mysqli_error());
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    prf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

?>
```

html

```html
<form  method=post action="processor.min.php">
  <div class=""> 
  <label for="manufacturer">Validation Employee</label></br>
    <input type="text-area" name="validationemployee" id="validationemployee" placeholder="Who Are You?" required="required"/>


  </div>
  <div class="field name-box">
    <label for="manufacturer">Device</label></br>
    <input type="text-area" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Model?" required="required"/>


  </div>
    <div class="field-box">
    <label for="model">Serial</label></br>
    <input type="text-area" name="serial" id="serial" placeholder="Serial Number?" required="required"/>


  </div>
    <div class="field-box">
    <label for="model">Lot Number</label></br>
    <input type="number" max="99999999999" name="lotnum" id="lotnum" placeholder="Lot number?" required="required"/>


  </div>

<div class="rTable">
<div class="rTableRow">
<div class="rTableCell"><h3></h3></div>
<div class="rTableCell"><strong></strong></div>
<div class="rTableCell"><span style="font-weight: bold;"></span></div></div>

  <div class="radio">
    <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableCell"><label for="sanitationmethod">Sanitation Method</><!---<span class="fb-required">*</span></div><div class="rTableCell">Power on Self-Test</div><div class="rTableCell">No Beeps, codes, or errors</div>--></div>
    <input type="radio" name="sanitationmethod" id="sanitationmethod" value="HD Shredder 4" required="required">HD Shredder 4</></br>
    <input type="radio" name="sanitationmethod" id="sanitationmethod" value="dd urandom" required="required">$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdx</></br>

  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableCell">
    <label for="validationmethod">Validation Method</><!--- <span class="fb-required">*</span></div><div class="rTableCell">Power on Self-Test</div><div class="rTableCell">No Beeps, codes, or errors</div>--></div>
    <input type="radio" name="validationmethod" id="validationmethod" value="dsumm" required="required">dsumm</></br>
    <input type="radio" name="validationmethod" id="validationmethod" value="xxd" required="required">xxd -a /dev/sdx</></br>

  </div>

    <div class="radio">
  <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableCell"><label for="passfail" >Pass or Fail</></div><!--<span class="fb-required">*</span></label></div><div class="rTableCell">Plug into Battery</div><div class="rTableCell">Charges the Battery</div></div>-->
    <input type="radio" name="passfail" id="passfail" value="1" required="required">Pass</></br>
    <input type="radio" name="passfail" id="passfail" value="0" required="required">Fail</></br>

  </div>

     <div class="field name-box">
     <label for="serial">Reason it failed</label></br>
     <input type="text-area" name="failcomment" id="failcomment" placeholder="Fail reason">


  </div>
<div class="fb-button form-group field-submit-button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Submit" style="default" id="Submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

processor.min.php

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

include("config.inc.php");
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $validationemployee = $_POST['validationemployee'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $serial = $_POST['serial'];
    $lotnum = $_POST['lotnum'];
    $sanitationmethod = $_POST['sanitationmethod'];
    $validationmethod = $_POST['validationmethod'];
    $passfail = $_POST['passfail'];
    $failcomment = $_POST['failcomment'];
}

$validationemployee = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $validationemployee);    
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $description);
$serial = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $serial);
$lotnum = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $lotnum);
$sanitationmethod = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $sanitationmethod);
$validationmethod = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $validationmethod);
$passfail = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $passfail);
$failcomment = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $failcomment);
### printing variables
echo $validationemployee ." ". $description  ." ". $validationmethod ." ". $sanitationmethod ." ". $passfail ." ". $failcomment;

mysqli_select_db($link,$db_name) or die ("no database");
$query  = "INSERT INTO " .$db_table. " (`lotnum`, `description`, `serial`, `sanitationmethod`, `validationmethod`, `passfail`, `failcomment`, `validationemployee`)
    VALUES ('$lotnum','$description','$serial','$sanitationmethod','$validationmethod','$passfail','$failcomment','$validationemployee');";

mysqli_query($link,$query);

if ($link->warning_count) {
    if ($result = $link->query("SHOW WARNINGS")) {
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        printf("%s (%d): %s\n", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
        $result->close();
    }
}

mysqli_close($link);

include("confirm.html");

#print_r($lotnum "Entered "$description" </br>"$serial"</br> with sanitationmethod of "$sanitationmethod);
?>
```

Comment: What is returned by `mysqli_query($link,$query)`?  Is there anything in `mysqli_error($link)`?  What is the runtime value of `$query`?

Comment: What does `var_dump($query);` output?

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will prevent any pesky quoting issues you may be having** Also check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) in case the query completely fails.

Comment: +aynber is right, `mysqli_real_escape_string` does not protect you completely! See here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741264/3533786

Comment: Warning count is not the same as error count. As @David wrote, you need to check the return value of mysqli_query() and print out mysqli_error($link) if you have any errors.

Comment: You also provide all the values as string, even if the underlying data is numeric. This is not a good practice either. Particularly not if you get an empty string instead of a number. Depending on MySQL settings, that could trigger an error.

Comment: Nothing shows for warnings

Comment: @Factulas again, warnings are not the same as errors. You may have an error, but 0 warnings.

Comment: string(231) "INSERT INTO datavalidator (`lotnum`, `description`, `serial`, `sanitationmethod`, `validationmethod`, `passfail`, `failcomment`, `validationemployee`) VALUES ('12','device','serial','HD Shredder 4','xxd','1','Passed','employee');"

Comment: Shadow - I have both
$results = mysqli_query($link,$select);
if (!$results) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    exit();
}
and 
if ($link->warning_count) {
    if ($result = $link->query("SHOW WARNINGS")) {
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        printf("%s (%d): %s\n", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
        $result->close();
    }
}

Comment: +aynber +nick.graziano I am aware of the risk for SQL Injection. I will do a prepared statement after.

Comment: PLEASE edit your question and provide the additional information there, it is too hard to read code /error messages from comments.

Comment: Not sure if i'm using this right. Im trying to see if anything is even being passed to the db var_dump($query->num_rows);

Comment: Add a check for _errors_ after `mysqli_query($link,$query);`; let us know if you get any.